# Using WPBakery Page Builder and Default Wordpress Elements

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wpbakery

I have purchased a WordPress theme and the theme comes with the WPBakery page builder.
My question is cannot we use the Page Builder elements and the default WordPress elements on the same page?

For example, I am trying to add a video on my home page. The theme supports only Video Modal or a YouTube Video Embedded player where a link to the YouTube video has to be specified. However, the video that I have is in my local and I do not wish to upload it in YouTube or any other platforms.

WordPress, by default provides a Video element and this element supports the functionality that I require, giving all kinds of options like AutoPlay, Loop, etc. 
However, if I select the page to be built using the WPBakery, then I do not get an option to choose the default WordPress elements.

Is this how its supposed to work or is there a way where I can use both WPBakery elements + the default WordPress elements?

**Edit 1:**
I cannot see the Hosted background option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Hosted Video Option in WP Bakery Plugin Row Element. Here you can easily paste the link of hosted video [ May be in your own server, or you can insert the upload video link from Media ]. Please find the attached image.

Hope it works for you.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi Tristup, I have edited my question. Please find the screenshot there. I am not able to see the option in the Text block options.
Also, since I am using a theme, the text block settings that I am getting is a bit different from the default Wordpress text block I guess.

Comment: Which version you are using?